# Android App not connecting to network which is on **localhost** and if trying to run on Real Mobile Phone

Tags: android, retrofit, genymotion

I have created one android app which communicate with Restful WebService by using **Retrofit**.It is performing good when running on **Genymotion **,means it is sending request and getting respond back.

But when I run it on **Real Mobile Phone** ,App is running but it is even not sending request also.Can anybody tell me why this is happening ?

**AfterEdit:** when we have

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                  .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://10.0.3.2:8082")
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
    RetrofitService service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);
    try {

        ServerResponse serverResponse = service.checkLogin(loginDetails);
 ...}
```

where their is Retrofit interface

```
public interface RetrofitService {

@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json" })
@POST("/VendorWebApplication/userLogin")
public ServerResponse checkLogin(@Body LoginDetails loginDetails);}
```

Now when it is caming to `service.checkLogin(loginDetails)` it is expected it should request to respected web service,which is happening correctly with genymotion.But when running on **Mobile Device** ,it is going upto `ServerResponse serverResponse = service.checkLogin(loginDetails);` but not even requesting to Respected URL also and moving forward.

Error:[image]

Comment: cant say anything without looking at the code

Comment: hi, please mention which kind of error you have get.

Comment: @Shreekant N have you checked your internet connection ?

Comment: @DarshanMistry my mobile device is connected to my PC through USB.and webService which it requesting is also created by me **notice URL** is http://10.0.3.2:8082...

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I have inserted little bit code **AfterEdit**.

Answer (score 0):

When we are trying to run android app in which it is connecting to WebService which is on **localhost**,

make sure when it is running on **Genymotion**,ip address should be like **http://10.0.3.2:8082/UrAddress** or http://10.0.2.2:8082/UrAddress

and when you are running it on real mobile device,make sure **MOBILE and PC should be connected to same Network** and instead of 10.0.3.2 insert your **PC's IP** address